# Can't connect to MongoLab on my host

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I have a problem connecting to MongoLab from my Node app. When I'm in local, everything works fine, but when I'm uploading it on my host (the awesome [Clever Cloud](http://www.clever-cloud.com/), you should check it out), it does not connect. I copy my code and the logs.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var client = new mongo.Db('tweets', new mongo.Server('ds051077.mongolab.com', 51077, {auto_reconnect: true, 'poolSize': 10}));
client.open(function (error, db) {
    if(error) { console.log(error); }
    db.authenticate('***', '***', function(err, success) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("MongoDB failed");
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }

        console.log("MongoDB client opened");
    });
});
```

An the logs

```
2013-03-13 14:13:38 npm install done
2013-03-13 14:13:39 info: socket.io started
2013-03-13 14:13:39 /home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:141
2013-03-13 14:13:39 ^
2013-03-13 14:13:39 throw new Error('Error connecting to database');
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at module.exports.MongoStore.__proto__ (/home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:141:15)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:383:7)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at connection.on.connectionStatus (/home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:93:15)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 Error: Error connecting to database
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at Db.open (/home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:247:16)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:327:14)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at Socket.errorHandler (/home/bas/app_1ae17610-f658-4923-87b1-0cc889719794/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:385:10)
2013-03-13 14:13:39 at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I have to say that I'm struggling to see the problem, as it works fine in local. Does anybody have an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would contact Clever Cloud and ask them if port 51077 is being blocked on your server.  They may need to punch a hole in a firewall to allow the connection.

Comment: Why this port ? Edit: Nevermind, I'm dumb ^^

Comment: Apparently, no, it's not blocked.

Comment: Do you have the ability to run arbitrary commands like ping on your server?  Try:

% ping ds051077.mongolab.com

Or:

% telnet ds051077.mongolab.com 51077

Comment: Nope I can't. It's an external host.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using a MongoDB driver version that's compatible with your database?  If your database is version 2.2+ it won't be compatible with older versions.  Also, if you are using 2.2+, you might consider using the new MongoClient way to connect instead:  http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html

Comment: It does look like there is a potential issue with the connection between your paas provider and mongolabs. I would suggest creating a quick script using the node socket to attempt a socket connection http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket. If it fails then it's a connection issue (firewall etc) between the providers.